# CSS image position relative to column widths OR screen size

Tags: css, image, position

Is it possible to position images relative to the center of a different section, or the center of a screen size?

I am trying to place a logo that's about 2.28:1 wide spanning across 3 sections, such that it overlays each individual section background but not the entire row background.

Furthermore, I would like to (although not absolutely necessary to) each section and each section of the logo be a different color. I've somewhat been able to achieve this by three different backgrounds and three different positions of the background (L section, L justified logo, etc). Although this looks good on a full screen, when the screen is smaller the logo is not positioned correctly.

I'm thinking that the ways to do this are to either position the L and R images relative to the center of the center column, or relative to the center of the entire window. How can this be done?

Website for reference: http://ironorrfitness.com

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired affect with the following code for the logo in the left section:

```
background-position: -webkit-calc(50% + 33vw) 60%;
background-position: calc(50% + 33vw) 60%;
```

and the following code for the logo in the right section:

```
background-position: -webkit-calc(50% + 33vw) 60%;
background-position: calc(50% + 33vw) 60%;
```

Each section used an image of the logo that was positioned the same, but in a different color for each section.